# "wrong constant name" error when generating a new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a new model like this:

```
rails generate model Tags name:string
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
base.rb:266:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name tags (NameError)
```

Any thoughts?  I tried changing Tags to ReportTags and it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Model names are singular - try

```
rails generate model Tag name:string
```

Comment: I did that and I'm still getting the same error with Tag.  Also tried ReportTag.  Any other thoughts?  This is just baffling.

Comment: O.K.  That was strange.  I just tried it again this morning and it worked.  Something must have gotten into a weird state and didn't clear up until I rebooted my VM.